# Why " sort file > file " would remove all the content of that file?

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

Today I'm learning sort command.

I find that, I can use

```
sort file1 > file2
```

To inject the sorted file into file2

But when I use

```
sort file1 > file1
```

file1 become empty!

Why?!

I know I can use -o flag to get the sort file1 into file1.

But why the second command produce an empty file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Output redirection by the shell clears the file's contents before the `sort` command is run.

From `man bash`:

> Before a command is executed, its input and output may be redirected using a special notation interpreted by the shell. [...]
>
> Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the expansion of word to be opened for writing [...].  If the file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to zero size.

Comment: So sorted writes an empty file into an empty file.

Comment: @Zen At least it'll be fast. :-)

Comment: It's really a easy way to empty a file which its shell you want to keep. Just '> file' it

Comment: I met a trouble now, as this method produce an empty file. How do I edit this file through command line? Like if I want to replace some words with sed.

Comment: @Zen If this is about sed, `man sed` will actually help you with this on the first page.

Comment: I saw the -i option, it perform a little different on OS X than on Linux. But learnt how to use it anyway

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel Beck has explained why that fails.

Here is a way to do that job the OP want.

```
sort file1 | tee file1
```

tee is a T-shape pipe which can write the buffer into the file and pass the buffer as output to the next pipe, here we just need to use its half power.

Comment: Be careful, though. If the first command reads as a stream rather than buffer the whole file (`sort` does the latter, but others won't), then you'll have a similar problem.

Comment: @Bob, I got you idea, like 'sed', so how can I modify a file safely in a command line?

Comment: I suspect your only option for a generic method (i.e. where the command itself doesn't provide some way) is to manually create a temporary buffer, e.g. a temp file, and either write to this buffer + copy it back or copy the file and read from the copy.